# Is it possible to programmatically capture iPhone 5S slow motion video?

Tags: iphone, ios, video, ios7

I couldn't find an answer to this question, and looking at Apples own apps like iMovie on iOS, the video picker does not offer a slow motion option on the iPhone 5S.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image picker offers very little control over the video. If you are willing to dive deeper into the APIs you can use `AVFoundation` to capture your video and manipulate the camera properties as you see fit.

iOS 7 introduces a new `AVCaptureDeviceFormat` class that will give you the maximum and minimum supported frame-rates for the capture device, and you can use these to set a custom frame rate on the camera itself. I don't have an iPhone 5S to hand so I can't actually verify whether this API goes all the way down to 120FPS.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Do you know of an working example project that makes use of AVCaptureDeviceFormat for a quick test?

Comment: Unfortunately not - I did have a quick look before I posted, but it's so new there's not much out there right now. However, it should be fairly easy to take one of Apple's `AVFoundation` sample projects and add a couple of lines to try out the new `AVCaptureDeviceFormat` class.